# dired - sort and hide by default

Tags: dired, sorting

More often than not, when I open a dired buffer, I press

- `(` to run `dired-hide-details-mode`
- `s` to run`dired-sort-toggle-or-edit`

What's a good way to have these done automatically every time I open a dired buffer?

Comment: Use [`dired-mode-hook`](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_dired_tips.html).  [Hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html) are the standard way to perform mode-specific customizations.

Comment: Thanks @Dan! I've added an answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Dan's comment on the original question.

This seems to work:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (dired-hide-details-mode)
        (dired-sort-toggle-or-edit)))
```