# dired-hide-details show size and date

Tags: dired

I can't see that there is anyway in `dired` to hide permissions and ownership, but show size and date.

As the only user on the system and using a version control system, my files generally belong to me and are read-write.

Comment: Vanilla Emacs offers nothing for this. Likewise [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus). But perhaps there is another library that offers it. I just hit `(` to peek and hit it again to hide `(`. But if you want to *keep* a certain set of details visible while hiding others then that's not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With stock emacs, you could try this:

```elisp
(require 'ls-lisp)
(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil)
(setq ls-lisp-verbosity nil)
```

That should do everything you need except for hiding the permissions.

Answer (score 3):

The `dired-details` package, available from melpa, allows you to hide and show detailed listings in `dired` by pressing `)` and `(`. Not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe useful as a work around until we find a way to pick and choose columns from the `ls` output to display.

## UPDATE

As @mikado points out, this feature is now part of Emacs without any packages, just by pressing `(` from a `dired` buffer. Neither the Emacs built-in version or the `dired-details` version allow you to select which columns of the `ls` output to show  & hide, though.

Comment: I'm using Emacs 25.2.1 where that functionality is already built in, but I don't think it lets me customize the display in the way I'd like

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize Emacs did that without a package nowadays. And you're right - it's all or nothing. I don't think there is an option to show part of a listing like you want, but it would be really useful if there was.

Comment: You can also hide the details by default: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27912/dired-sort-and-hide-by-default